# mysql multi layered self referencing nested join

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, self-join

I have 2 tables. `tb_device` and `tb_site_object`.

`tb_device` is quite simple:

```
| id | station_id |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 6          |
| 2  | 6          |
| 3  | 9          |
```

`tb_site_object` looks like this:

```
| id | type    | upper_site_id |
|----|---------|---------------|
| 1  | top     | null          |
| 2  | type2   | 1             |
| 3  | type3   | 2             |
| 4  | station | 3             |
| 5  | top     | null          |
| 6  | station | 5             |
```

The relationship between tables is like this: `tb_site_object` has many devices when `type` column in `tb_site_object` is equal to `station`.

As can be seen `tb_site_object` table self references itself. Rows with `station` type points to another row with type `type3` and rows with `type3` references rows with `type2` and naturally they also reference `top` and close the *climbing loop* via `upper_site_id`.
Since `top` rows start the chain they have always `null` value for `upper_site_id`.

There is a **but:**
type `station` can point to any type above breaking the station.

Assuming I explained the tables correctly (hopefully), this is my question:
I need to make an sql query for fetching devices given with only `id` of `tb_site_object`.

so if id is 1 I have to crawl down to 4 and make a join with `tb_device`. if given id is 3 then it's straight to 4.

this is how I am fetching stations:

```
select
  lvl1.type lvl1_type,
  lvl1.upper_site_id lvl1_upper,
  lvl2.type lvl2_type,
  lvl2.upper_site_id lvl2_upper,
  lvl3.type lvl3_type,
  lvl3.upper_site_id lvl3_upper,
  lvl4.type lvl4_type,
  lvl4.upper_site_id lvl4_upper
from
  tb_site_object as lvl1
  left JOIN tb_site_object lvl2 ON lvl1.id = lvl2.upper_site_id
  left JOIN tb_site_object lvl3 ON lvl2.id = lvl3.upper_site_id
  left JOIN tb_site_object lvl4 ON lvl3.id = lvl4.upper_site_id
where
  lvl1.type = 'business';
```

EDIT 1
`station_id` in tb_devices is foreign key for tb_site_object's `id`.

EDIT 2
Type column always starts with top and ends with station. top -> type2 -> type3 -> station. Only station can go up and end the chain early

Comment: Your description contains no description of how the two tables are related.  Where is the reference from one table to the other?  You mention "make a join with tb_device".  Explain how the tables are related.

Comment: Which row relates to device? Top,station or something else? which column relates to device? Are the top...station always discrete and always a station for a top? If there is a top without a station what do you want? Can top...station overlap eg top,top,station,top ?

Comment: It may be that recursion is appropriate what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: `station_id` column in tb_devices points to `id` in tb_site_object @JonArmstrong

Comment: You must have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: It always starts with top and ends with station. top -> type2 -> type3 -> station. Only station can go up and end the chain early @P.Salmon

Comment: db is aws aurora 2.7.2